# Reverting S3 BucketPolicy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I was playing around with AWS S3 BucketPolicy. My intention was to allow access to bucket only to my username. I wrote following incorrect policy:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1542608345364",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1542608327277",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::abcd",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "mohit.choudhary"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1542608343623",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::abcd",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, now I don't have access to that bucket anymore. How can I revert the bucket policy?

Answer (score 2):

By *reverting* you mean the previous version of the bucket policy? I don't think it's versioned, sorry (unlike IAM Policies - see [Versioning IAM Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-versioning.html)).

We can however fix your policy, there is a couple of issues:

1. The *[Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html)* should be the IAM User ARN:

   ```
   "Principal": {
     "AWS": [
        "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/mohit.choudhary"
     ]
   }
   ```

   Replace 123456789012 with your account number.
2. The *[Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html)* should have both the bucket and the objects wildcard:

   ```
   "Resource": [
     "arn:aws:s3:::abcd",
     "arn:aws:s3:::abcd/*"
   ]
   ```

---

Alternatively you can **delete the bucket policy** altogether using the Delete button at the top:

[image: Delete S3 Bucket policy]

Hope that helps :)

Comment: By reverting, I mean, how can I delete s3 bucket policy or somehow grant me access to that bucket again.

Comment: @mohit you can simply delete the policy using the *Delete* button at the top.

Comment: @mohit updated the answer with policy deletion instructions

Comment: The problem is I don't have access any more as I was not the bucket owner. No matter how much IAM permissions you've you cannot do anything, if you're not bucket owner. Yes bucket owner can delete the policy.

Comment: @mohit that’s quite an important information that shouldn’t have been left out from the question. I’m afraid your only option is to ask the bucket owner to delete it as the policy won’t let you do it.

Comment: Yeah I was just figuring out stuff. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I am not the bucket owner. No matter what permissions you've in IAM, if you're not the bucket owner, and you're denied access by bucket policy, you cannot do anything.

Only way to revert the policy back is bucket owner should delete bucket policy.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-s3-evaluates-access-control.html

Comment: The next time include *all relevant information* in the question. Offerring an obvious solution that can’t work because you didn’t mention you’re not the bucket wastes *my* time and doesn’t help *you* either. Never mind, next time be more careful with bucket policies ;)